# How come my twig code does not render the template in my views file?

Tags: templates, twig, atom-editor, grav, osclass

I am just learning twig.
This is my code:

```php
<?php
 require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../views/');
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

 echo $twig->render(
  'front.twig.html',
  array(
    'slogan' => 'Learning Twig So I Can Theme Grav CMS',
  )
);

?>
```

It does not render my template. I am using the code from an online tutorial. I believe my file system is correct and I have properly installed composer and twig.
What am I doing wrong?

The file produces this output:

```
render( 'front.twig.html', array( 'slogan' => 'Learning Twig So I Can Theme Grav CMS', ) ); ?>
```

Comment: You do have a buggy `\`` after the opening parenthesis of `$twig->render`

Comment: oh, that wasn't in my original code. Thanks for pointing that out. Must have been a mistype when I copied and pasted here.

Comment: I edited it out of the question then

Comment: thanks! I was running the wrong version of Twig, but am still running into errors I will have to post elsewhere. I got this code to work. I can't figure out how to write a proper get method.